# Showing Regular space is hereditary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have tried showing that the regular property is hereditary. The attempt is as below:

Let (A, $\tau'$) be the subspace of (X, $\tau$).

Next let C be a closed set of A and p $\notin$ C, then $C=D \cap A$ for some closed set D in X. Next, since $p \in X$, and X is T1 also {p} is a closed set.

However, how would we ensure that the set D is disjoint with {p} and even though we can find disjoint open sets U,V such that D $\subset U$ and $p \in V$, can we take $U \cap A$ and $V \cap A$ to obtain sets $U', V'$ such that $C \subset U', p\in V'$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no difference whether $X$ is $T_1$ (and by the more common definition of regularity it need not be<sup>1</sup>): you don’t care whether $\{p\}$ is closed. All you need to know is that $p\notin D$, and this is immediate from the fact that $p\in A\setminus C$, while $D\cap A=C$. Thus, $D$ is a closed set in $X$ not containing $p$, and regularity of $X$ ensures that there are disjoint $U,V\in\tau$ such that $D\subseteq U$ and $p\in V$. And then, as you said, $U\cap A$ and $V\cap A$ are disjoint open sets in $A$ separating $p$ and $C$.

<sup>1</sup> The traditional (and preferable) definition of regularity is that a space $X$ is regular if for any closed set $C$ in $X$ and point $p\in X\setminus C$ there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U$ and $C\subseteq V$. A space that is both regular and $T_1$ is a $T_3$-space. Unfortunately, some people reverse the definitions of *regular* and $T_3$, so that the $T_k$ properties no longer form a hierarchy. If your *regular* includes $T_1$ (so that it’s my $T_3$), then in order to show that it’s hereditary, you must also show that the $T_1$ property is hereditary. If, as is likely, you’ve already done this, you should still mention the fact.